# Finding values starting with a specific piece of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a *.txt file and I keep some codes of some files in it. Format is the following:

```
code1, a/b/c/1.jpg
code2, a/b/c/2.jpg
code1, a/b/c/3.jpg
code2, a/b/d/4.jpg
code3, a/b/d/5.jpg
```

My purpose is finding the files in the same folder with the same codes (duplicates). All the file names are different. If the same code occurs in different folder like `code2, a/b/c/ and code2, a/b/d/` I want to skip it. Right now I have the following code which searches a specific code in the whole *.txt document:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  
dataDict = dict()
for row in reader:
    if any (row):
        if row[0] in dataDict.keys():
            dataDict[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            dataDict[row[0]] = [row[1]]
```

But this gives me the duplicates in different folders. However, I want to find the duplicate files exactly in the same folder.

Edit:The title is not clear. I did not know how to describe this in the title.

Comment: `If the same code occurs in different folder like code2, a/b/c/ and code2, a/b/d/ I want to skip it.`
What do you mean `to skip it`?

Comment: I mean if the same code occurs in different folders I do not account it as a duplicate. Only if a code occurs at least two or more times in the same folder I consider it as a duplicate.

Comment: okay, that's better.  It is still unclear what you want to find though.  Seems like you want to find duplicate file entries.  How do codes come in?  Do you want to find duplicate files with same corresponding codes?

Comment: Code is checksum. Yes I want to find the duplicates by using md5 checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  
dataDict = dict()
for row in reader:
    if any (row):
        code, filename = row
        _, dir_path = filename.rsplit('/', 1)
        if dir_path not in dataDict.keys():
            dataDict[dir_path] = {}
        if code not in dataDict[dir_path]:
            dataDict[dir_path][code] = []
        dataDict[dir_path][code].append(filename)
duplicates = []
for k_dir, v in dataDict.items():
    for _, paths in dataDict[k_dir].items():
        if len(paths) > 1:
            duplicates.append(paths)
return duplicates
```

First part is sorting codes and files together

The second part is detecting duplicates and returning them